# Matlab: fmincon and inequality constraints (implementation issue)

Tags: matlab, optimization, constraints

I'm working on an optimization problem in Matlab, but unfortunately, I'm stuck. 
I want to maximize \theta using the function fmincon, but this particular problem depends on $n$, and $n$ can get very large. There are $n-1$ inequality constraints, all defined with the relation:

```
For all i \neq j \leq n : \theta - (x_i - x_j)^2 - (y_i - y_j)^2 \leq 0.
```

So $c(x)$ is an (n-1)x1 - vector.

I'm looking for a way to implement this, so that I don't have to write a new matlab file for each different $n$. (and as you can imagine, when n gets large, that would be one heck of a job)

Any help would be dearly appreciated. 
Cheers!

**EDIT :** I now have created an extra m.file, just for this constraint:

```
function constraint(n)
%this is a function which creates the constraints of the distance. 

for i= 1: n
    for j= 1:n
        if j==i
            continue;
        end
    (x(i)-x(j))^2 + (y(i)-y(j))^2;
    end
end
```

But the problem now is that matlab goes over the elements one by one. For example: it doesn't calculate (x(1) - x(4))^2 + (y(1) - y(4))^2.

Any idea on how to solve this one? 
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that your function wouldn't at some point calculate that value (when i = 1 and j = 4). The main issue seems to be that your function doesn't return anything, or take in `x`.  According to [this](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/writing-constraints.html#brhkghv-16), a constraint function should return two things:

> Nonlinear constraint functions must return both c and ceq, the
>   inequality and equality constraint functions, even if they do not both
>   exist. Return empty [] for a nonexistent constraint.

So first, we need to make sure our constraints are saved into an output vector, `c`, that `c` and an empty `ceq` are returned, and that our function takes both `x` and `n`. There might be prettier ways of doing it but

```
function [c, ceq] = constraint(x,n)
%this is a function which creates the constraints of the distance. 

counter = 1;

for i= 1: n
    for j= 1:n
        if j==i
            continue;
        end
    c(counter)=(x(i)-x(j))^2 + (y(i)-y(j))^2;
    c = c+1;
    end
end 

ceq = [];

end
```

Next problem: this function takes two inputs, but `nonlcon` as an input to `fmincon` needs to take only one, `x`.  We get around this by wrapping this function in an anonymous function (`n` needs to be predefined), so in the actual `fmincon` call you would set it to be something like `@(x)constraint(x,n)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how do you solve it then for y and theta? I mean: theta needs to be maximized, x and y are unknown vectors. So you have to put in something like @(x,y,theta)? 
(I'm really sorry for the beginners question, but I've never got any training in matlab)